# Chart.js don't show

Tags: typescript, chart.js

I'm trying to show a chart with dynamic data, but it doesn't show. If I write data directly it works. This is the variables declaration, I try 2 forms, once is commented.

```
//Variable con los datasets de los gráficos
//datasets: [{ label: string, data: [{ x: string, y: number }] }] = [{ label: '', data: [{ x: '', y: 0 }] }];
  datasets: [{ label: string, data: number[] }] = [{ label: '', data: [] }];
  newDataset: {label:string, data:number[], borderColor: string } = {label:'', data:[], borderColor:''};
//Variable para el objeto data de cada dataset a mostrar en el grafico
//data: [{ x: string, y: number }] = [{ x: '', y: 0 }];
  data: number[]=[];
//Array con las etiquetas del eje x del gráfico
  etiquetas: string[] = [];
```

......

```
Chart.register(...registerables);
    let canvasCo2 = document.getElementById('grafico') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    console.log("antes del grafico:");
    let grafico = new Chart(canvasCo2, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels:this.etiquetas,
        datasets:[]
       }
    });
```

I put values from:

```
this.etiquetas.push(this.fultima.toString());
this.newDataset.data.push(Number((this.co2 / this.contaMedidasHora).toFixed()));
this.newDataset.label = this.dispService.getNombre(this.informeService.parametros.codigos[i]),
this.newDataset.borderColor = this.obtenerColor();
```

In console browser I see the dataset with data array but I don't see the chart. First I see the labels array, then the datasets array [console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTppR.png)

This is my chart declaration:

```
        grafico.config.data.datasets.push(this.newDataset);
        grafico.config.data.labels=this.etiquetas;
```

....

```
  grafico.update();
  console.log("Grafico pintado")
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for all.

I had done a test whith a new variable, and make a console.log with it , and my RES variable, and I see one diference. With the test variable I see the chart, wiht my RES variable don't. In console.log RES is defined like [] and TEST (prueba) like [{}], I think that's the problem but I don't know to fix it.
[image]

COMPLETE CODE

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DispService } from 'src/app/servicios/disp.service';
import { InformeService } from 'src/app/servicios/informe.service';
import { MedidasCo2Service } from 'src/app/servicios/medidasCo2.service';
import moment from 'moment/moment.js';
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-informe-medidas-co2',
  templateUrl: './informe-medidas-co2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./informe-medidas-co2.component.css']
})
export class InformeMedidasCo2Component implements OnInit {
  //Variable con los datasets de los gráficos
  //datasets: [{ label: string, data: [{ x: string, y: number }] }] = [{ label: '', data: [{ x: '', y: 0 }] }];
  //datasets: [{ label: string, data: number[], borderColor:string }] = [{ label: '', data: [], borderColor:'' }];
  //newDataset: {label:string, data:number[], borderColor: string } = {label:'', data:[], borderColor:''};
  //Variable para el objeto data de cada dataset a mostrar en el grafico
  //data: [{ x: string, y: number }] = [{ x: '', y: 0 }];
  data: number[]=[];
  //Array con las etiquetas del eje x del gráfico
  etiquetas: string[] = [];
  //Fecha con la hora para calcular las medias de las medidas de esa hora
  fecha: string = formatDate('01/01/1900 00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm', 'es');
  //Contador de medidas por hora, irá de 1 a 12 que son las máximas
  contaMedidasHora: number = 0;
  //variable con el co2 medio calculado
  co2: number = 0;
  //Variable que indica si se tiene que grabar la medida con la media de la hora
  grabar: boolean = false;
  //Conversión de fechas a tipo date válido
  fdesde: Date = new Date();
  fhasta: Date = new Date();
  //Variable para grabar la ultima medida calculada
  fultima: string = '';
  //Variable para obtener aleatoriamente un color de línea del gráfico
  color: string = "#";

  constructor(private medidasCo2Service: MedidasCo2Service,
    private informeService: InformeService,
    private dispService: DispService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fdesde = new Date(moment(this.informeService.parametros.fdesde, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS').format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00'));
    this.fhasta = new Date(moment(this.informeService.parametros.fhasta, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS').format('YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59'));
    let datasets=[{}];
    // Chart.register(...registerables);
    // let canvasCo2 = document.getElementById('grafico') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    // console.log("antes del grafico:");
    // let grafico = new Chart(canvasCo2, {
    //   type: 'line',
    //   data: {
    //     labels:this.etiquetas,
    //     datasets:[]
    //    }
    // });


    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("2.calculando medidas");
      //Inicializamos el array de datasets del gráfico, habrá tantos como códigos de dispositivos ha seleccionado en la pantalla
      datasets.splice(0, datasets.length);
      //Recorrer el array con los códigos de dispositivos
      for (let i = 0; i < this.informeService.parametros.codigos.length; i++) {
        //this.newDataset.label = this.dispService.getNombre(this.informeService.parametros.codigos[i]),
        //this.newDataset.borderColor = this.obtenerColor();
        //Buscar las medidas por dispositivo
        this.medidasCo2Service.getMedidas(this.informeService.parametros.codigos[i]).subscribe((data: { status: number; respuesta: any[]; }) => {
          //Si ha encontrado medidas
          if (data.status == 200) {
            //Filtrar las medidas por las fechas seleccionadas como parámetros en la pantalla
            let respuesta_corta = data.respuesta.filter((x: { createdAt: string | number | Date; }) => {
              return new Date(x.createdAt).getTime() >= this.fdesde.getTime()
                && new Date(x.createdAt).getTime() <= this.fhasta.getTime();
            });
            //Inicializar el array con las medidas de cada dispositivo
            this.data.splice(0, this.data.length);
            //Con cada medida se calculan las medias por hora y se graban en el array de datos
            for (let j = 0; j < respuesta_corta.length; j++) {
              this.calcularMediasHora(formatDate(respuesta_corta[j].createdAt, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:00', 'es'), Number(respuesta_corta[j].CO2));
              this.fultima = formatDate(respuesta_corta[j].createdAt, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:00', 'es');
            }
            //Se ha finalizado el bucle sin grabar la última medida
            this.data.push( Number((this.co2 / this.contaMedidasHora).toFixed()) );
            //this.newDataset.data.push(Number((this.co2 / this.contaMedidasHora).toFixed()));
            this.etiquetas.push(this.fultima.toString());
            //Una vez calculadas todas las medias por hora de todas las medidas encontradas
            //para ese dispositivo entre las fechas seleccionadas, se graba el dataset para 
            //el grafico.
            datasets[i]={
               label: this.dispService.getNombre(this.informeService.parametros.codigos[i]),
               data: this.data,
              //data: [5,10,15,20,41,23,34,15,63,21],
               borderColor: this.obtenerColor()
            };
            //grafico.config.data.datasets.push(this.newDataset);
            //grafico.config.data.labels=this.etiquetas;
          }
        });
      }
      console.log("antes de resolve:", datasets);
      resolve(datasets);
    });

    console.log('1. Proceso iniciado..');

    p.then(res => {
      console.log("3.RES:", res)
      this.verGrafico(res);
      //grafico.update();
    })
  }

  calcularMediasHora(hora: string, co2: number) {
    if (this.fecha == "01/01/1900 00:00") {
      this.fecha = hora;
    }
    if (this.fecha != hora) {
      //se ha cambiado de hora, se guardan los valores almacenados 
      //y se inicia nueva hora con los nuevos valores
      this.data.push( Number((this.co2 / this.contaMedidasHora).toFixed()) );
      this.etiquetas.push(this.fecha.toString());
      //this.newDataset.data.push(Number((this.co2 / this.contaMedidasHora).toFixed()));

      this.co2 = co2;
      this.contaMedidasHora = 1;
      this.fecha = hora;
    } else { //es la misma hora, se acumulan los datos
      this.grabar = false;
      this.co2 += co2;
      this.contaMedidasHora++;
    }
  }

  verGrafico(res: any): boolean {
    //Visualizamos los gráficos
    Chart.register(...registerables);
    let canvasCo2 = document.getElementById('grafico') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    console.log("ETIQUETAS antes del grafico:",this.etiquetas);
    console.log("RES antes grafico", res);
    let prueba = [
      {
      borderColor: "#7C66B2",
      data:  this.data,
      label: "con medidas"
      },
      {
        borderColor: "#7C6623",
        data:  [467,345,654,465,544],
        label: "con medidas 2222"
      }
    ];
    console.log("prueba:",prueba);
    let grafico = new Chart(canvasCo2, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels:this.etiquetas,
        //datasets:res
        datasets: prueba
       }
    });
    console.log("Grafico pintado")
    return true;
  }

  obtenerColor():string {
    let color: string = "#";
    let simbolos: string = "0123456789ABCDEF"
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
      color = color + simbolos[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)];
    }
    return color;
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are trying to render the chat before data arrives. What is `this.co2`?Where it comes from? Can you post the whole code?